# Exclude import statement from dependency

Tags: spring

I'm working on an application which has a dependency A that has a spring context associated with it and it further refers to another dependency B. In my main application, I'm trying to cut down useless dependencies and exclude the final dependency B. When I run my application, I'm getting error that says the following,

> nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   cannot be opened because it
>   does not exist

This is due to dependency A referring to dependency B's context xml. Is there a way to ignore this import and run my application with minimal dependencies i.e., only Dependency A?

Comment: I didn't understand if you have already done something to exclude the dependency B. Are you using Maven to manage your dependencies?

Comment: Using maven, the dependency B was excluded.